# Euler characteristic of a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a group of affine transformations

Tags: group-theory, affine-geometry

Let $G$ be a  subgroup of the group of invertible affine transformations of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is given that $G$ acts freely and properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Must the Euler characterisitc of the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $G$ be zero ?

Edit: Properly discontinuously means: for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists an open set $V$ containing $x$ such that for every nonidentity $g\in G$ we have $gV\cap V=\emptyset$

My question seems to be related to the [Chern conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%27s_conjecture_(affine_geometry)) , but I am not knowledgeable enough to judge if the two questions are equivalent or not.

Comment: Define "properly discontinuously". There are at least 2 very different definitions of this term.

Comment: @MarkSaving   Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not equivelant to the Chern conjecture, which deals with affine manifolds.

The condition of being a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by affine maps is equivelant to being a complete affine manifold. In this case the quotient has Euler characteristic zero. This was proved by Konstant and Sullivan in 1975 (see the History part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%27s_conjecture_(affine_geometry)).